# Need data driven solution when versioning comes in to the picture

Tags: c#

Please refer the attached image, my code set is trying to update the database once it reads the value from a file, I am having versioning related problems though.

[image]

With New version of implementation my file is going to have different file parameter name stored in the file, now I need to make sure that my code set is smart enough to be able to update latest database's point either old version file is opened or new version file is opened.
I tried using translation table it works fine upon reading but while saving I would only want to translate the App label points if they are going to be saved for older version of the file for new version I want to save the database points as is to the file.

Comment: Hey Mathias how did you show the image beside the content?

Comment: Check out the markdown for yourself (use the `edit` link to see it)

Comment: aha found it thanks Mathias R Jessen